# Hoes does the HAML compiler know when a line has ended?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

The HAML has a very good advantage to ERB, this advantage is not having closing tags.

```
ERB
<strong><%= item.title %></strong>

HAML
%strong= item.title
```

However, I was always taught that HTML had closing tags so that it knew when to stop doing something.  In this case stop making the text bold.

Is the HAML compiler superhuman?  Or is there some hidden method to knowing when something happens.

Comment: Something is wrong with the highlighting, it would be great if something knew how to sort that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HAML is based on **indentation**:

```
%p
 Hello
 %span= " Popey"
```

Will generate HTML like this:

```
<p>Hello<span> Popey</span></p>
```

The HAML compiler is not superhuman, it just knows that if the indentation of the next line is bigger than the current one, then this next line is wrapped in the container.

Comment: Thanks for this, really cleared things up!  Will accept answer in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

HAML is based on indentation. The compiler bases its logic in nested directives. For example:

```
%strong Some bold text
%strong
  All of
  these lines are
  bold text
This text is not bold
```

More info here: http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html

Comment: Thanks for this!  Great to have the lin in there for further reading.

Comment: @PopeyGilbert yes HAML is good fun. If you are starting you might wanna check `SLIM` (http://slim-lang.com/) as well. Not as popular but it's similar to HAML